# How can I nest a class within another?

Tags: javascript, class, nested

So I'm trying my hand at JavaScript "classes" to try and clarify and simplify some of my code.  What I have is something like this:

```
function action (name, vActor, vTarget) {
    this.name = name;
    this.vActor = vActor;
    this.vTarget = vTarget;
    this.addRoll = addRoll;
    this.children = {};
}
function addRoll (name, diffMod, dice, success, critSuccess, failure) {
    this.children[name] = {} ;
    this.children[name].diffMod = diffMod;
    this.children[name].dice = dice;
    this.children[name].success =       {condition: success,        outcome: {}};
    this.children[name].critSuccess =   {condition: critSuccess,    outcome: {}};
    this.children[name].failure =       {condition: failure,        outcome: {}};
    this.children[name].addSuccess = addSuccess;
    this.children[name].addFailure = addFailure;
    this.children[name].addOutcome = addOutcome;
}
```

Is this the right way to go about this?  My main question is regarding who owns the "this" object in the "function addRoll()" section.  I'm assuming that "this" still belongs to the action 'class'.  I also am uncertain of the syntax regarding starting a new blank object and assigning stuff using dot notation.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you define functions that you will call using `new`, start them with capital letter (it's a convention in order to remember to add `new`)

Comment: There are no "classes" in JavaScript; there are functions, and there are instances created from functions.

Comment: Yeah, thinking about classes in JS is not ideal, since prototypes are more powerful than classes I'd suggest learning the JavaSctipt way instead of trying to emulate other languages

Comment: JavaScript is not a class-based programming language.  You will do better by embracing its prototypal paradigm than trying to fit a square block into a circular hole.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignoring function binding and calling apply or call, the `this` property is the owner of the method. Calling...

```
addRole(...)
```

The `this` property points to the global `window` object. If you had an object `{}` or instance `new Something()` called `x` with the function `addRole` and called it...

```
x.addRole(...)
```

The `this` property is `x`.

**Additional** You have correctly assigned the function to the action object so when you call...

```
var a = new action(...);
```

And then call

```
a.addRole(...);
```

The `this` property is the `a` instance of `action` you have created. To prevent it being called as a global function and adding properties to the `window` you could assign it to a `prototype`. The `prototype` object has some powerful features to build inheritance but for now simply changing...

```
addRole(...) {...}
```

To the following...

```
action.prototype.addRole = function(...) {...}
```

And removing the assignment in action...

```
this.addRole = addRole
```

Will prevent the function accidentally being called without an owner

**Further** You could rewrite the way you assign the children in addRole to make greater use of object literal notation...

```
function addRoll(name, diffMod, dice, success, critSuccess, failure) {
    this.children[name] = {
        diffMod: diffMod,
        dice: dice,
        success: {
            condition: success,
            outcome: {}
        },
        critSuccess: {
            condition: critSuccess,
            outcome: {}
        },
        failure: {
            condition: failure,
            outcome: {}
        },
        addSuccess: addSuccess,
        addFailure: addFailure,
        addOutcome: addOutcome
    };
}
```

You could also refactor the code to use classes for the children as follows.

```
function Action(name, vActor, vTarget) {
    this.name = name;
    this.vActor = vActor;
    this.vTarget = vTarget;
    this.children = {};
}
Action.prototype.addRoll = function(name, role) {
    this.children[name] = role;
}

function Role(diffMod, dice, success, critSuccess, failure) {
    this.diffMod = diffMod;
    this.dice = dice;
    this.success = success;
    this.critSuccess = critSuccess;
    this.failure = failure;
}
Role.prototype.addSuccess = function(...) {...}
Role.prototype.addFailure = function(...) {...}
Role.prototype.addOutcome = function(...) {...}

function Condition(condition) {
    this.condition = condition;
    this.outcome = {};
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll need to check into prototypes.

Comment: No probs, when I was starting out this book really helped http://www.amazon.co.uk/JavaScript-Design-Patterns-Recipes-Problem-Solution/dp/159059908X

Comment: It does have some appeal to it seeing code nicely packaged up into classes...

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, if `addRoll` is called from an instance of `action` then the `this` object will still belong to `action`.

The way you do it is a bit confusing for me though, I usually assign methods of constructors (what you call classes, but not really) through their `prototype` property

like this

```
function action()
{
...
}

action.prototype.addRoll = function(){...}

var instance = new action();
instance.addRoll();
```

Comment: `addRoll` is bein set on instances of `action`.

Comment: Oh, i'm sorry, I didn't read the `this.addRoll = new addRoll`, I've corrected my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You asked quite a few questions here, let me try to answer them one at a time
so this is your code, simplified version

```
function Action (name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.addRoll = addRoll;
}
function addRoll (name, diffMod, dice, success, critSuccess, failure) {
    ...
}
```

1. how to start a new blank object?
   you use the "new" key word, so to create a new "action" object, you do `var newAction = new Action('hello')`
2. what does "this" refer to in javascript?
   "this" refers to the caller of the function. An simple example:
   `var newAction = new Action('hello world');`
   `newAction.addRoll(//...);`
   in this example, the "this" inside addRoll function is "newAction"
   but if you were to invoke "addRoll" directly, "this" refers to the "Window" object if you are using a browser.